# Spring MVC gives error 404 not found with InternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a new web application but my servlet cant seem to map to my controller

**Web.xml**
[image]
**servlet.xml**
[image]
**Controller**
[image]
**Project explorer**
is there anything wrong with the placement of my jsp?
[image]

I have configured the web.xml and servlet.xml and also annotated my Controller but i keep getting error 404 not found and my console does not show any error.